# Given a PHP associative array and a "current" key, calculate the "next" and "previous" elements (with looping)

Tags: php, arrays, navigation

I realize there are dozens of similar questions on SO, but I can't seem to find an answer that fits my application. I'm doing some page navigation and have the following PHP array where keys are page identifiers and values are URL slugs:

```
$pages = array(
  'a' => '/pages/first',
  'b' => '/pages/another',
  'c' => '/pages/third',
  'd' => '/pages/something-else'
);
```

Say my "current" page is `'a'`. I would like to have `$next_page` get set to `'b'` *and `$previous_page` get set to `'d'`*. Of course, since the "current" page is `'a'` I can do this to get `$next_page`:

```
while(key($pages) !== null && key($pages) !== 'a') next($pages);
$next_page = next($pages);
```

However, since `'a'` is the first element of the array, the following sets `$previous_page` to `false`:

```
while(key($pages) !== null && key($pages) !== 'a') next($pages);
$previous_page = prev($pages);
```

So given an associative array such as `$pages` above, how can I get both the "next" and "previous" keys even when the "current" key could be the first or last element of the array?

Note: `$pages` must be an associative array with arbitrary string keys.

Comment: [array_keys()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) should be a useful function here.... allows you to identify the position numerically, so you can then check the key for the -1 and +1 positions

Comment: @obertwbradford What a previous key do you expect for 1st element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$key = 'a';

$keys = array_keys($pages);
$cur = array_search($key, $keys);
$next = $keys[($cur + 1) % count($keys)];
$prev = $keys[($cur - 1 + count($keys)) % count($keys)];

echo $pages[$prev] ."\n";
echo $pages[$next] ."\n";
```

result

```
/pages/something-else
/pages/another
```

Comment: index = 2; count = 3; nextIndex = (index + 1) % count; nextIndex is 0, element at index 0, your code works as circle

Comment: *Say my "current" page is 'a'. I would like to have $next_page get set to 'b' and $previous_page get set to 'd'. * - The asker wants circle, i understand

Comment: Nice technique to give wraparound of prev/next

Answer (score 0):

Working with numeric keys may be easier but here is your way by moving the pointer.  Just check for `false` and call `end()`:

```
while(key($pages) !== 'a' && next($pages));
if(($previous_page = prev($pages)) === false) { $previous_page = end($pages); }
```

And you'll have the same issue with `next()` if it is at the end, `d` in your example. So just check for `false` and call `reset()`.

```
while(key($pages) !== 'd' && next($pages));
if(($next_page = next($pages)) === false) { $next_page = reset($pages); }
```

The logic could probably be shortened a bit.